# How to install GNU linux in iball compbook excelance?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, laptop

I have an [iball compbook excelance](http://www.iball.co.in/product/excelance/11187) Notebook-PC that ships with Windows 10 pre-installed. I want to install Linux in dual boot with windows 10. However, I am unable to install any Linux distro on this machine.

Calameres Installer seems to fail during `grub-install` with error

```
failed to register boot entry, i/o error
```

It appears that the laptop has non editable NVRam.

How should I proceed with Linux installation now?

Comment: @People who are down voting - I challenge you to get the above stuff done.

Comment: Hi, since we don't have a specific tag on the target system, providing additional hardware details will be helpful. Also read our [help page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you haven't done already.

Comment: @Sathyam All the hardware, software and accessories details are already listed in the link shared in the question above.

Comment: Considering that 1) notebooks often have custom solutions that make out-of-the-box installations difficult and 2) that the kali distribution doesn't target running on a maximum number of devices, I'm afraid your goal is the combination of difficult tasks. I suggest to take one step a time and try to run a live debian from your stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have the same laptop, have tried multiple Linux distros, in short this thing CANNOT boot up Linux (although I had some success with Jide's android based Remix OS, but it was unusable).

Why it's so incompatible?

1. This 'laptop' is not a proper laptop per se, the motherboard has EMMC based storage that operates at 32 bit which is in turn paired to an intel 64 bit processor, this strange design confuses Linux boot loaders as they expect a 64 bit based storage and components working together with a 64 bit processor. 32 bit based Linux expects all components working at 32 bit, while 64 bit Linux expects all components working at 64 bit. Windows 10 boot loader doesn't have any problems with this.
2. The UEFI BIOS on this thing is locked down to only allow windows based boot loaders (specifically windows 10 & 8), you cannot change the UEFI to LEGACY to even allow windows 7 to be installed.
3. This machine uses SDIO connections for connecting to hardware, emulating it as a standard PCI connection. This is a typical behaviour of all windows based tablets currently in market (so this laptop is basically a windows tablet with keyboard and trackpad attached). So even if by any chance we hack the Linux boot loader to boot up Linux, Linux wont be able to recognize the hardware components (like no wifi, Bluetooth, camera, etc) as currently SDIO drivers are not availiable for linux, although you can also surpass that limitation by creating your own custom drivers, but that would be a heck lot of work & stability is not guaranteed.

coming back to my earlier point, I was able to run Remix OS (64 bit ver) on this thing, it booted up, but was sooo slow (it was trying to initialize drivers but it was failing in the background and thus CPU was actively being used making machine hot, and really really laggy), if you're going to try & run it, trust me it will frustrate you enough to reboot and go back to windows.

I have not given up on this little machine, but as of now sorry buddy, no Linux for now.

Comment: I am facing all the issues as well. Lets see if we can get the linux drivers at some future dates as a positive expectancy.

Comment: It's been years. Any update on this?

Comment: This is not completely true, I have successfully Installed manjaro on my machine, you just need to grub install with `--target=i386-efi` because this laptop has a 32bit uefi. All hardware is detected and it works perfectly, except the fact that performance is not great. because of slow EMMC